# How to properly set-up ValueNotifier between parent and child widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state, parent-child, draggable

I have a parent `StatefulWidget` in one file like `parent.dart` and a child `StatefulWidget` in a separate file `child.dart`. My `ChildWidget` has a `DraggableScrollableSheet` which is wrapped in a `NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>`. In the `onNotification` of the `DraggableScrollableNotification` I'd like to send values up to the `ParentWidget` using a `ValueNotifier`.

Currently I declare the `ValueNotifier` as state in the `ParentWidget`, then in the parent's widget tree I call `ChildWidget(passedValueNotifier: theParentValueNotifierState)`.

Then in the `ChildWidget` `onNotification()` I'll do `theParentValueNotifierState.value = someValueISet;`

Then in the `ParentWidget` I'll have a `ValueListenableBuilder`.

Is this how you can have a child widget send up data to a parent which can then rebuild only certain parts of the tree?

Sometimes I get this exception in VSCode:

> FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. This
> ValueListenableBuilder widget cannot be marked as needing to
> build because the framework is already in the process of building
> widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the
> build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This
> exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets
> before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
> Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build
> phase. The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called
> was:   ValueListenableBuilder The widget which was currently
> being built when the offending call was made was:
> DraggableScrollableSheet)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a code example?

Comment: I think you are doing it correctly but there is a possibility that the parent & child widget is being rebuilt same time, Just add some delay before notifying the parent. Then it will indeed work, accordingly, you can debug & fix it.

Answer (score 0):

put `valueNotifier` outside parent state, because if `setState()` called, value notifer get dirty and rebuild :

my_value.dart :

```
ValueNotifier<int> parentCount = ValueNotifier(0);
```

parent.dart :

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  const Parent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Parent> createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        ChildWidget(onChildWidgetChanged: (currentCount) {
          parentCount.value  +=  currentCount;
        }),
        ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: parentCount,
            builder: (context, value, _) {
              return Text('count: $value');
            })
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

child.dart:

```
typedef OnChildWidgetChanged = void Function(int count);

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final OnChildWidgetChanged onChildWidgetChanged;
  const ChildWidget({Key? key, required this.onChildWidgetChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          onChildWidgetChanged(2);
        },
        child: const Text("Increase"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where would you dispose of the ValueNotifier?